# How to pass I2C addresses to Adafruit CircuitPython code? (Running ADS1115)

Tags: raspberry-pi2, i2c, adafruit, adafruit-circuitpython

I'm trying to run two Adafruit ADS1115s off of one Raspberry Pi, using two I2C addresses (0x48, 0x49). The address for each device can be set by tying the ADDR pin high (0x49) or leaving it floating (default, 0x48). I've confirmed that each board works when the address is set to 0x48, and running "i2cdetect 1" confirms that both boards are connected at the correct addresses.

I can successfully run this sample [code](https://github.com/adafruit/Adafruit_CircuitPython_ADS1x15/blob/master/examples/ads1x15_ads1115_simpletest.py)

My question is this: How do I get the code to read from I2C address 0x49 instead of 0x48? I can't find documentation anywhere. Please advise.

Comment: I think these all address pins are defined and you cant program it to change but you can use some sort of external helper devices. May be this https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/63469/change-i2c-address-of-tmp102 will give you some ideas

Comment: I can change the addresses of the boards, that's not a problem. I'm wondering how I set the code to read from address 0x49 instead of the default 0x48.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since there is a Python library the rules of Python language are applied, in particular OOP with class inheritance. That said, The class ADS1115 is inherited from ADS1x15, which in its turn has `__init__()` method (in OOP *constructor*) defined as follows:

```py
def __init__(self, address=ADS1x15_DEFAULT_ADDRESS, i2c=None, **kwargs):
```

which means that it knows about at least two positional arguments with names `address` and `i2c` with default values `ADS1x15_DEFAULT_ADDRESS` and `None` respectively. So, you need in your code redefine them, i.e. instead of `ads = ADS.ADS1115(i2c)` use

```py
ads = ADS.ADS1115(address=0x48, i2c=i2c)
```

For the second put there `0x49`.

Answer (score 0):

Aha!
`ads1 = ADS.ADS1115(i2c, address=0x49)`

Source: https://github.com/adafruit/Adafruit_CircuitPython_ADS1x15/issues/20