# Jetson nano with AMG8833 through GPIO always get Remote I/O error

Tags: gpio, i2c, nvidia-jetson-nano

As title mentioned, I tried to extract some data from AMG8833 through GPIO on Jetson nano, but always get

```
[Errno 121]Remote I/O error...
```

My AMG8833 SDA connect to GPIO pin 27, and SCL connect to pin 28. I have already tried

```sh
sudo i2cdetect -y -r 1
```

Then only shows 29, I have no idea about this, and still cannot work...

Is there anyone has any other solutions about this issue? Please share with me, I will be very appreciated for your help.
Following is the python code...

```python
import busio
import time
import board
import adafruit_amg88xx
i2c = busio.I2C(board.SCL, board.SDA)
amg = adafruit_amg88xx.AMG88XX(i2c)
while True:
    time.sleep(1)
    for row in amg.pixels:
        # Pad to 1 decimal place
        print(["{0:.1f}".format(temp) for temp in row])
        print(row)
        print("")
    print("\n")
    time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: However after few minutes, I use sudo i2cdetect -y -r 1 there is no any number... then I use sudo i2cdetect -y -r 0 there is a number 69. I know that means there is a i2c device connect to number 69 but why sometimes here sometimes not, and also I would like to know how can I get data from 69? Thanks.

Comment: And when I got 69, then I ran the above code, I got message: No I2C device at address 69... Why ?

Comment: First of all, it's I²C bus, which has no relation to GPIO mode of the pins, unless you are **emulating** it with bitbanging, which I think is **not** the case here. Second, the libraries often require RW address (means shifted left by 1), so you can try 0xd2 instead.

Comment: Also read this: https://stackoverflow.com/q/60102070/2511795 (hmm... looking into the implementation the default address is 0x69, should work then, means check the pins you supply to `busio` module)

Comment: @0andriy Thanks for your reply! I am not so sure "RW" address that you mentioned, could you explain more? And I just tried to add address 0xd2 and 0x69 but there are both still Remote I/O error, and 0x69 get another error "No I2C device at address 69". How should I check the pin supply to busio? I checked the wires and no problems there.